# how to properly set this variable after calling some functions?

Tags: jquery

I have the following script.

I am trying to set showMsg variable after saySomething() function is called. It needs to be set to either true or false depending on what I do with saySomething function.

With this, I get undefined. How do I set showMsg after saySomething function is called?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   var showMsg;

   (function() {
       saySomething("something something darkside, something something complete!",
                 function() { showMsg = true;  console.log('aww yis') },
                 function() { showMsg = false; console.log('ooo noo') } );
})();


    console.log(' showMsg = ' + showMsg);

    function saySomething(strText, functionOne,functionTwo){
      console.log("From saySomething : " + strText);
    }  

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to actually execute one of the functions for it to have an effect. I have no idea what your logic might be, but something like the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   var showMsg;

   (function() {
       saySomething("something something darkside, something something complete!",
                 function() { showMsg = true;  console.log('aww yis') },
                 function() { showMsg = false; console.log('ooo noo') } );
})();


    console.log(' showMsg = ' + showMsg);

    function saySomething(strText, functionOne,functionTwo){
      alert(strText);
      if (strText === "something something darkside, something something complete!") {
        functionOne();
      } else {
        functionTwo();
      }
    }  

});
```